# How to do a Query on SQL Server 2008 R2 using a subquery / function on GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, in-subquery

When I execute this query, it works fine:

```
SELECT     
pr.pr_nombre , cl.cl_nomcorto, 
mc_cant * dbo.tipo_cambio(cr.mo_id,3,mc_fecha)/0.951 as Interes,
mc_cant * dbo.tipo_cambio(cr.mo_id,3,mc_fecha)/0.951*.049 as WH,
(select pr_id from dbo.nonplusultra(cr.pr_id) where pr_renew_ref is null) as Agrupador
FROM   movcuentas mc
inner join corridas cr on mc.cr_id =  cr.cr_id
inner join clientes cl on cr.cl_id = cl.cl_id
inner join prestamos pr on cr.pr_id = pr.pr_id
WHERE     (mc_concepto = 'Amort Int') AND (tm_id = 3) AND MONTH(mc_fecha) = 2 AND YEAR(mc_fecha) = 2017 
ORDER BY pr.pr_nombre
```

I get this:

[Query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGB5h.jpg)

Now I need to show it adding columns "Interes" and "WH" on records with same "Agrupador", something like this:

```
SELECT     
pr.pr_nombre , cl.cl_nomcorto, 
sum(mc_cant * dbo.tipo_cambio(cr.mo_id,3,mc_fecha)/0.951) as Interes,
sum(mc_cant * dbo.tipo_cambio(cr.mo_id,3,mc_fecha)/0.951*.049) as WH,
(select pr_id from dbo.nonplusultra(cr.pr_id) where pr_renew_ref is null) as Agrupador
FROM   movcuentas mc
inner join corridas cr on mc.cr_id =  cr.cr_id
inner join clientes cl on cr.cl_id = cl.cl_id
inner join prestamos pr on cr.pr_id = pr.pr_id
WHERE     (mc_concepto = 'Amort Int') AND (tm_id = 3) AND MONTH(mc_fecha) = 2 AND YEAR(mc_fecha) = 2017 
GROUP BY pr.pr_nombre , cl.cl_nomcorto, (select pr_id from dbo.nonplusultra(cr.pr_id) where pr_renew_ref is null)
ORDER BY pr.pr_nombre
```

And I get this error message:

Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure it even makes sense to put that subquery in the `GROUP BY` list.  If it is correlated, then you should wrap it in an aggregate function somehow in the `SELECT` clause.  If it's not correlated, then just remove it from `GROUP BY` because it isn't doing anything.

Comment: The idea is to use column "Agrupador" to Group rows with the same value, In the data result included, it would add "Interest" and "WH" for rows with a value of "731"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make use of CTE here?

```
;WITH CTE as 
(
SELECT     
pr.pr_nombre , cl.cl_nomcorto, 
mc_cant * dbo.tipo_cambio(cr.mo_id,3,mc_fecha)/0.951 as Interes,
mc_cant * dbo.tipo_cambio(cr.mo_id,3,mc_fecha)/0.951*.049 as WH,
(select pr_id from dbo.nonplusultra(cr.pr_id) where pr_renew_ref is null) as Agrupador
FROM   movcuentas mc
inner join corridas cr on mc.cr_id =  cr.cr_id
inner join clientes cl on cr.cl_id = cl.cl_id
inner join prestamos pr on cr.pr_id = pr.pr_id
WHERE     (mc_concepto = 'Amort Int') AND (tm_id = 3) AND MONTH(mc_fecha) = 2 AND YEAR(mc_fecha) = 2017 
ORDER BY pr.pr_nombre
)
select pr_nombre,cl_nomcorto,sum(Interes),sum(WH),Agrupador
from CTE
group by pr_nombre,cl_nomcorto,Agrupador
order by pr_nombre
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh, it returns the exact same result as the original query, it launches but it doesn't group by the "Agrupador" column. Thank you!!.

Comment: You mean the result from CTE is not grouping by Agrupador? Can you please share the snapshot? There must be some difference in records-whitespace or something.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, in fact there was a whitesapece in a record that kept it from working correctly, otherwise the solution you suggested works like a charm. Thank you!!

Comment: @Rolando M, that's great!! Please mark it as answer. Thank you!!